# Changing position of cancel_comment_reply_link and other elements of comment form

Tags: comments, comment-form

How would I move elements of the WordPress comment form, which is called in comments.php with the following:

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

For instance, I'd like to wrap `cancel_comment_reply_link` in h4 tags and place it below `get_post_reply_link`. But I don't see any way to do it.

Formerly, all the code for the comment form was there in `comments.php`. You could easily move the elements around and place them where you wanted. Now, all of those elements are buried as functions in `comments-template.php`.

Has someone created a function and callback, similar to the one that exists for `wp_list_comments`, that provides access to the elements of the comment form?

If so, we might more easily edit the code to move links, labels and fields.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to take a look at Otto's post all about the comment form and functions, here: http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-the-comment-form/

If you want to cut to the chase, you can add this function to your functions.php:

```
function my_fields($fields) {
$fields['new'] = '<p>Some new input field here</p>';
return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_fields');
```

Then set new defaults, changing your HTML and Class/ID's as you like:

```
$defaults = array(
    'fields'               => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
    'comment_field'        => '<p class="comment-form-comment">...',
    'must_log_in'          => '<p class="must-log-in">...',
    'logged_in_as'         => '<p class="logged-in-as">...',
    'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">...',
    'comment_notes_after'  => '<dl class="form-allowed-tags">...',
    'id_form'              => 'commentform',
    'id_submit'            => 'submit',
    'title_reply'          => __( 'Leave a Reply' ),
    'title_reply_to'       => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s' ),
    'cancel_reply_link'    => __( 'Cancel reply' ),
    'label_submit'         => __( 'Post Comment' ),
);
```

In this case, I'm unsure if you can apply a class or ID directly to the "cancel reply link". You can try wrapping it in a `<span>` tag here, or just use some creative javascript to find it and apply a class:

```
$('a:contains("Cancel Reply")').addClass('cancel-reply-link');
```

Comment: Tom, I've been up and down Otto's post, inside and out. At this point, I've given up on doing anything with a link in the comment form but add some CSS style. But as I am not an accomplished scripter, let me at least ask this question: Say I want to change the text of `cancel_reply_link` to, "Cancel your reply". What **specific** code would I paste in functions.php to accomplish this?